# Open a Popup inside Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

Hi i have a Login button and after that if the login went well I have to close the Login popup and open another one. This is my code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="login" class="popupCenter" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:300px;" data-theme="a">
        <li data-role="divider" data-theme="b">Login</li>
        <li>
            <label for="user">User:</label>
            <input type="text" name="User" id="user" data-mini="true" class="myClass" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" id="password" data-mini="true" class="myClass" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" />
    <p id="labelError" style="visibility: hidden; color: red">Username o Password errati</p>
    <a id="loginBtn" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check" data-theme="b">Login</a>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="infoParticelle" class="popupCenter" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:300px;" data-theme="a">
        <li data-role="divider" data-theme="b">Info particelle</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" />
</div>


$('#loginBtn').click(function () {
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/login",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: {
            dir: "tokens",
            usr: user,
            pswd: password
        },
        success: function (data) {
            token = data;
            if (token == null) {
                document.getElementById("labelError").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else {
                console.log('Token: ' + data);
                $('#login').popup('close');
                $('#infoParticelle').popup('open');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

All my `$('#infoParticelle').popup('open')` don't work but outside the click button it works. THe funny thing is that the close popup `$('#login').popup('close')` works.. Thanks

Comment: Add also the relevant HTML code. Did you debug it in browser?

Comment: Show me the response of `console.log('Token: ' + data);`

Comment: that's correct.. It also closes the #login popup.. it just doesn't open the other one

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have more than one `id="infoParticelle"` in your HTML markup?

Comment: yes.. as you can see i have now edited and added the html..

Comment: I can see the html posted, but maybe you load dinamically other html, or the same id is maybe found in different views. There can be only one `id="infoParticelle"` :)

Comment: yes I have also changed the name everywhere just to be sure.. but nothing

Answer (score 0):

When i tried your code, i got an error saying that popup() was not a function. 
So i went to jquery ui documentation and found that to create popup, u have to use the .dialog method : https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default . For instance :

```
$("#infoParticelle").dialog();
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/5764/
You just have to place your ajax call again, and things should work.